# Is it possible to add DRM in Android VM image

Tags: android, virtual-machine, drm, android-drm

I downloaded Android VM Image (Android-x86 9.0-R2 Pie) and running it in VMWare on my windows computer. I want to use an app which provides streaming video. The app runs, however whenever I run any video it just returns an error. I can not debug the error, however I think it might be due to missing DRM on my VM image. See DRM Info Screenshot. Is there any possible way to add DRM in android VM ? Emulators like Blue Stacks have same problem too

[DRM Info Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgfiv.png)

Answer (score 1):

DRM on an emulator or VM image is usually an issue for Android, or any system, as the more secure DRM's are linked to the HW or the trusted execution environment on the device itself.

Even if the emulator or VM will allow you leverage the underlying platforms built in DRM, e.g. PlayReady built into your Windows machine, this is not a particularly useful test as this is not how it will run on an actual Android device, if that type of testing is your goal.